# Jquery - displaying images on the category page using Lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

**What do i have right now**...

I have a page X and on that I have different categories like A, B, C. Each category is represented by an image from it's gallery. Now when I click this category image a new page opens up with all the images from that category and when I click one of the images on this second page Jquery Lightbox comes into action and start doing it's magic.

**What, I want to do is**...

When I click that category image on page X, instead of opening a new page with all the images from that category, I want Jquery Lightbox to come into action right on page X with all the images from the category I clicked.

**Please help me acheive this**

Comment: You'll have to post your code, or even better - a link to your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not give [jQuery Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home) a try? All you need to do is follow the simple step-by-step instructions [here](http://fancybox.net/howto) and you can have the same fancy-looking style on your website too.

There are some good examples on the homepage (towards the bottom of the page) that you might be interested.